# jQuery File Uploader Issue On Post Form Of My Site

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-file-upload, jscript

I am attempting to use a jQuery File Uploader plugin on the post_form.php page located on the admin panel for my site replacing my current uploader.  In end result I am looking to have the uploader linked to the post_form where it dynamically allow clients on my site to create posts with uploads of image, music, and video files from their admin panel account. These posts will feed to their respective profile pages based on the client who submitted the post.

One of the issues I am having is when I insert the part of the jQuery file uploader code for the submit button the preview table shows up, but everything is underneath the submit button and shifts the other fields in the post form out of line to the right. I would like to have the plugin on my post form page appearing above both the submit, status and category fields as it is shown  in the demo on the site of the jQuery plugin. The next thing I am trying to do after that is make sure the jQuery UploadHandler.php file is merged with my current postcontroller.php file to utilize the features and functions of the plugin while keeping the file upload path of the uploads/ folder on my sever, and feed the post made via the post_form to the user on my site's profile page based on the client/user id of created poster when they click the submit button after filling in the form.

If you someone can assist me in resolving this issue I would greatly appreciate it and be more than happy to credit you for your help. Thank you all in advance and I hope I made everything clear as I am a new user here.

Below is the part of the code from the jQuery File Uploader plugin on my post_form

> code for the 'Post Title', 'Description', and 'URL' text fields placed here

```
                    <tr>
                        <th>Upload:</th>
                        <td width="250">
                        <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
                        <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
                        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
                        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
                        <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
                            <div class="fileupload-buttons">
                                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                                <span class="fileinput-button">
                                <span>Add files...</span>
                                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                                </span>
                                <button type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="cancel">Cancel upload</button>
                                <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- The global progress state -->
                            <div class="fileupload-progress fade" style="display:none">
                                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                                <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
                        <table role="presentation"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
                        </form> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php if(isset($data['row'])){?>
                    <tr>
```

> code for 'Submit', 'Cancel' and 'Reset' buttons placed here

```
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
            <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
                <div class="slides"></div>
                    <h3 class="title"></h3>
                    <a class="prev">‹</a>
                    <a class="next">›</a>
                    <a class="close">×</a>
                    <a class="play-pause"></a>
                    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
                </div>      
            </div>          

        </div>
        <!--  end content-table-inner ............................................END  -->
        </td>
        <td id="tbl-border-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="sized bottomleft"></th>
        <td id="tbl-border-bottom">&nbsp;</td>
        <th class="sized bottomright"></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
<!--  end content -->
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<!--  end content-outer......END -->
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="start" disabled>Start</button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="error">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>Delete</button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
```

> script lines pointed to links online provided in the plugin placed here

```
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'wmlmusicguide.com' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/',
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
            .addClass('btn btn-primary')
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .text('Processing...')
            .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('<br>')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
                .text('Upload')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            if (file.url) {
                var link = $('<a>')
                    .attr('target', '_blank')
                    .prop('href', file.url);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .wrap(link);
            } else if (file.error) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                $(data.context.children()[index])
                    .append('<br>')
                    .append(error);
            }
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index) {
            var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('File upload failed.');
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
// Initialize the jQuery UI theme switcher:
$('#theme-switcher').change(function () {
    var theme = $('#theme');
    theme.prop(
        'href',
        theme.prop('href').replace(
            /[\w\-]+\/jquery-ui.css/,
            $(this).val() + '/jquery-ui.css'
        )
    );
});
// Post Form Validate
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#postForm').validate({
            errorElement: "div",
            rules: {
                name: { required: true },
                details: { required: true },
                category: { required: true }
            }
        });
        $('#restform').click(function(){
            $('#postForm')[0].reset();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Would you be able to trim your text (or at least split it into paragraphs)? And also work your code to a minimal example that still replicates your problem? As it is there is too much text and too much code in your question.

Comment: I thank you for your kind feedback and observation. My apology for that I hope the edit I made reads better now. I tried to provide the code in snapshots but the site says I don't have enough reputation/credentials to do so as yet. Being I'm new I didn't know the best way to show the code in the best available way without it being too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the jQuery file-uploader to show on the post_form.php page for my site by including

```
                    <td colspan=2 width="100%">                 
                    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
                    <table role="presentation"><tbody class="files"><textarea cols="60" rows="6"></textarea></tbody></table>

                    <div class="rfloat">
```

at the beginning of the file-uploader code

```html
<tr>
            <th valign="top">Upload:</th>
      <td colspan=2 width="100%">     
      <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
      <table role="presentation"><tbody class="files"><textarea cols="60" rows="6"></textarea></tbody></table>
      
      <div class="rfloat">
      <form>
      <label for="theme-switcher">Theme:</label>
      <select id="theme-switcher" class="pull-right">
       <option value="black-tie">Black Tie</option>
       <option value="blitzer">Blitzer</option>
       <option value="cupertino">Cupertino</option>
       <option value="dark-hive" selected>Dark Hive</option>
       <option value="dot-luv">Dot Luv</option>
       <option value="eggplant">Eggplant</option>
       <option value="excite-bike">Excite Bike</option>
       <option value="flick">Flick</option>
       <option value="hot-sneaks">Hot sneaks</option>
       <option value="humanity">Humanity</option>
       <option value="le-frog">Le Frog</option>
       <option value="mint-choc">Mint Choc</option>
       <option value="overcast">Overcast</option>
       <option value="pepper-grinder">Pepper Grinder</option>
       <option value="redmond">Redmond</option>
       <option value="smoothness">Smoothness</option>
       <option value="south-street">South Street</option>
       <option value="start">Start</option>
       <option value="sunny">Sunny</option>
       <option value="swanky-purse">Swanky Purse</option>
       <option value="trontastic">Trontastic</option>
       <option value="ui-darkness">UI Darkness</option>
       <option value="ui-lightness">UI Lightness</option>
       <option value="vader">Vader</option>
      </select>
      </form>
      </div>
               <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
<form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="fileupload-buttons">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="fileinput-button">
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
            <button type="reset" class="cancel">Cancel upload</button>
            <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <!-- The global file processing state -->
            <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="fileupload-progress fade" style="display:none">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            <!-- The extended global progress state -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table role="presentation"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
</form>
<br>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="start" disabled>Start</button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="error">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>Delete</button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
```

[my post_form page with the jQuery fileuploader showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XMe6.png)